# Expo 49 error on building react-native-reanimated@3.3.0 - Could not find appcompat-1.6.1.aar

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo, react-native-reanimated

I'm member of a team. I can not build the project on my pc but other teammates can. What can i do? What cause the problem? What is the different between my pc and others?

There is some errors in building `react-native-reanimated 3.3.0` with `appcompat-1.6.1.aar`

additional info:

- Expo SDK 49
- react native 0.72.6
- react-native-reanimated ~3.3.0

```
s@s-NUC11TNHi5:~/Desktop/myapp$ npx expo run:android --variant debug
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
 ℹ️  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-updates-gradle-plugin' (expo-updates@0.18.16)

> Configure project :expo

Using expo modules
  - expo-application (5.3.1)
  - expo-constants (14.4.2)
  - expo-eas-client (0.6.0)
  - expo-file-system (15.4.4)
  - expo-font (11.4.0)
  - expo-image-loader (4.3.0)
  - expo-image-picker (14.3.2)
  - expo-json-utils (0.7.1)
  - expo-keep-awake (12.3.0)
  - expo-linear-gradient (12.3.0)
  - expo-manifests (0.7.2)
  - expo-modules-core (1.5.11)
  - expo-modules-core$android-annotation (1.5.11)
  - expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor (1.5.11)
  - expo-print (12.4.2)
  - expo-sharing (11.5.0)
  - expo-splash-screen (0.20.5)
  - expo-structured-headers (3.3.0)
  - expo-system-ui (2.4.0)
  - expo-updates (0.18.16)


> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
Android gradle plugin: 7.4.2
Gradle: 8.0.1
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build. 
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo', ':expo-modules-core', ':react-native-gesture-handler', ':react-native-safe-area-context', ...

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.6.1.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Could not find appcompat-1.6.1.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.6.1/appcompat-1.6.1.aar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 4s
56 actionable tasks: 49 executed, 4 from cache, 3 up-to-date
Error: /home/s/Desktop/myapp/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: /home/s/Desktop/myapp/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/home/s/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (/home/s/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnGradleAsync (/home/s/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/platforms/android/gradle.js:72:46)
    at Object.assembleAsync (/home/s/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/platforms/android/gradle.js:52:18)
    at runAndroidAsync (/home/s/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/run/android/runAndroidAsync.js:36:24)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```